# Solr search query for advanced search

Tags: solr

I'm using solr 4.2. And I've implemented Advanced search in my application. In this search, one option is there for 'include all these words'. so whenever i put any word or any phrase without stop words, it works fine but with stop words, it returns no result. 
For example: 
Query: purchase tune
This query works fine but if i put query like:'i would like to purchase tune'
then it gives no results.
Why is so? And what i need to do?
Also for this kind of search I was using 'mm' parameter in solr. But now using 'q.op'.

In solr i'm adding param q.op as following
params.add("q.op","AND");
and query as
params.add("q",query);

Comment: can you show us the query you use and the field definition that you use it on?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: just edited the question and shown how m adding params

Comment: remeber that an AND is very strict. how is the result you are expecting to get back?

Answer (score 0):

Do you encounter the problem with the Dismax Handler and the mm parameter?

The DisMax handler has an issue with stopwords:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3085

In this ticket you find some workarounds:

> Typical solution is to not use stopwords or harmonize stopword lists
>   across all fields in your QF, or relax the MM to a lower percentag.
>   Sometimes these are not acceptable workarounds, and we should find a
>   better solution.

Perhaps "harmonize stopword lists" is a suitable soluation for your problem.